# VBA Autofilter Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure why I am getting the error. Basically my code reads in a user input from a Userform and then it autofilters depending on the selection.

```
Sub Review()

   Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Dim MasterList As Worksheet
   Set MasterList = wb.Sheets("Locations")
   SelectItem = "Full Fee Amount & Mutual Fund"
   RowCountTotal = 1

    If SelectItem = "Full Fee Amount & Mutual Fund" Then
    
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
            "Full Fee Amount"
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-99
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            "Mutual Fund Redemption"
            
    ElseIf SelectItem = "Full Fee Amount & Cash Transfer" Then
    
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
            "Full Fee Amount"
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-99
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            "Cash Transfer"
    
    ElseIf SelectItem = "Outstanding Amount & Cash Transfer" Then
        
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
            "Outstanding Amount Only"
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-99
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            "Cash Transfer"
    
    ElseIf SelectItem = "Outstanding Amount & Mutual Fund" Then

        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
            "Outstanding Amount Only"
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-99
        MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            "Mutual Fund Redemption"
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Error Selecting. Program will now exit"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I am getting the error

> run-time error 1004 - autofilter method of range class failed

as soon as I try to do the autofilter. It worked earlier when I did not have any if statements but now it has issues. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: And what is `RowCountTotal`? Is it a number, when the error appears? And why do you need the `SmallScroll Down` for this example?

Comment: run-time error 1004 - autofilter method of range class failed

Comment: RowCount total is the total length of the sheet, and yea you are right I should remove smallscroll down. I tried the A1:AB1 range for autofilter but that still gave me the error

Comment: Try to make it a [mcve], that means that if someone copies and pastes your code will get the same error. A good idea is to hardcode the values like `RowCountTotal` and leave only 1 of the conditions, the one producing the error, in order to replicate it easier.

Comment: Ok I added  a few things, idk if that helps

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
            "Full Fee Amount"
is throwing the erorrs. (basically whenever I call autofilter)

Comment: RowCountTotal is always 1. Can you set an autofilter on a single row?

Comment: Yea, but I still got the same error